# $this->view->layout()->setContentKey('') problem!

Tags: zend-framework, plugins, layout, view

i set a new **contentkey** for showing menu in right column of my site.like this:

```
public function menuAction()
{        
    $this->view->layout()->setContentKey('menu');

}
```

this is layout code:

```
<div class="center_col"><?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?></div>
<div class="right_col"><?php echo $this->layout()->menu; ?></div>
```

but there is a prob!! after setting menu contentKey every action result showing in right column (content don`t work!)

i have a plugin for menu action , i think it is that reasone!

this is my plugin:

```
class Places_Controller_Plugin_ActionSetup extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
public function dispatchLoopStartup( Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

    if (!$front->hasPlugin('Zend_Controller_Plugin_ActionStack')) {
            $actionStack = new Zend_Controller_Plugin_ActionStack();
            $front->registerPlugin($actionStack, 97);
        } else {
        $actionStack = $front->getPlugin('Zend_Controller_Plugin_ActionStack');
    }

        $menuAction = clone($request);
        $menuAction->setActionName('menu')->setControllerName('index');
        $actionStack->pushStack($menuAction);

}}
```

i nead menu action call in all pages , so  i use of this plugin!

is there any way for solve my prob?!

---

answer with Marcin and SMka help :

```
 public function menuAction()
{        

    $this->view->placeholder("menu")
                  ->append($this->view->render("menu/menu.phtml" ));

}
```

Comment: Did you consider using placeholder view helper? In this situation, maybe it would be more suited than changing the content name.

Comment: i checked that, but it can`t manage in action method (or i couldn`t found any thing for that), i have to use of bootsrap file for manage that! i prefer manage  menu in action method

Comment: afsane. You can access placeholder view helper in your actions as, e.g. $this->view->placeholder('my-placeholder').

Answer (score 1):

in your Menu action just do render to named segment

```
// Renders my/login.phtml to the 'form' segment of the
// response object
$this->render('login', 'form');
```

no need `layout()->setContentKey`, this method is for other things